# How was Tekken 3 cinematic intro created (software used, process, effect ...etc)?

Tags: animation, 3d, render, game-engine, game-physics

Apologies if this is a very specific and out of the blue type of question. Tekken 3 was one of the best games that left a lasting impression on me, growing up, especially the cinematic intro. For me it's still one of the best and coolest game cinematic intros ever, even compared to this era (giving it's been over 20 years now since the game's release). Even though I'm a software developer, I've always been intrigued by how such amazing cinematics intros are created. I've researched on Google everywhere, but unfortunately couldn't find a source that discloses such information. I know it's been over 20 years since and the game is quite old, but I still find it strange that there's no discussion anywhere online on how its amazing cinematic intro was created (what software(s) was used, how the cinematic effect was created ...etc). The best resource info I could find, simply talks about the game characters, moves ..etc. Nothing about the opening cinematic intro. Just for those who need a reference as to what I'm talking about, here's the video from YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsvtUxEFQaU.
I'm aware it's a very complicated process that requires a highly experienced team to work on it, but I simply want to know what software and what kind of processes/effects were used (even guesses from experienced animators/developers would suffice) and as much information about the process as possible, would be really appreciated. There are numerous tutorials online about how to make computer animations on 3D std max, Maya, Unity and Unreal, but they all look like children Disney animations or animation from the actual game graphic itself, not the cinematic effect rendering you experience from Tekken 3 intro. If you watch its intro you will know what I mean. I would really appreciate any help and would be very intrigued to learn the process if somebody could provide me with a direction and some information on the software and processes used, just from a very high level view.
Thank you so much in advance for the help. You will literally be answering one of my main life's mysteries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but they all look like children Disney animations or animation from the actual game graphic itself

I'm sorry, but did we watch the same video? It's entertaining for sure but visually nothing impressive.

This doesn't look like an in-game cinematic so it's probably using a 3d animation package like 3DsMax/Maya/Softimage/etc.. These packages are also used for feature films so I'm not sure where you're getting at that it all looks like children Disney animations. They can also be used for live action for photo realistic renders. Though these days 3DsMax is mostly used for games, Maya is what's mainly being used for films as it's what the studios are using (for the most part, there's exceptions). These packages also include solutions for particle effects, and cloth simulations. Right now Houdini is king for these 2 though.

Of course what matters most is the skills from the team to make the most out of the software.

The process generally goes like this:

1. Create a script to define the story
2. Create concept art for characters and locations
3. Create assets (3d models/textures/shaders)
4. Rig the assets so they can deform
5. Animate the assets into shots (modeling/rigging/anim can work in parallel)
6. Do character effects on your finished shots (cloth, hair, rigid dynamics. This depends on your budget and is optional)
7. If you're using any other software for lighting/effects, you probably need to export your scene to cache data (alembic is a popular format)
8. Render everything out
9. Use a compositing software to add all different elements together and make final tweaks to the shot (optional)

I'm still missing a few stuff, especially for bigger productions, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thank you v much for the answer @Green Cell. Regarding your first comment, apologies, I should've said that it's a subjective point of view of course, especially given that perhaps my childhood nostalgia plays a big part in liking the video so much. Also factoring in the music, realistic: particals; shading and lighting effect; as well as camera and scene transitions and the scenes themselves could've all contributed to making the video that extra entertaining and impressive, and made me bias for giving massive credit to an otherwise fairly average graphic for this day and age ...

Comment: ... I definitely agree with you, scoring it on graphic visual alone, not impressive for this day & age. Finally, regarding the steps you mentioned: for step 6, could you point me to a good article that I could further read on this step, if possible? For step 7, 8 and 9, what software would you recommend for these steps, from your experience? Also, do you think motion capture was used, given the characters movements were so realisitic. If so, is there a way to mimic close to realistic movement without having to hire expensive motion capture studio (kind of like hack if you will)? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry you mentioned Houdini package,would that fall under step 6 or 7? Thanks and sorry for the many questions.

Comment: Houdini is a 3d package that's fantastic for effects and simulations, as it's based on procedural nodes. It has a steep learning curve though and is awful for animation and modeling. If it's your first 3d package just stick with Max or Maya, as they have complete solutions from assets to animation to rendering. I find this place is solid to learn from, though not all lessons are free: cgcircuit.com. For post work (steps 7, 8, 9) just stick with whatever 3d package you are using. You don't want to over complicate your process unless you already know what you're doing.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the helpful answer. I'll start looking at Maya and Max :)